# Unique value in coulmn2 respect to column1 in sql

Tags: java, mysql, unique-constraint

I have an sql table in which there are two column `State` and `SongInState`.
Now I am having a scenario here, where `State` and `SongInState` columns can have any non unique value but any `State` can't have same `SongInState` value.
Table structure

```
ID     State     SongInState
1      AR        Dream on
2      MN        Dream on
3      TX        Hard sun
4      AR        I got a name
```

See i can have same state and songInState but not SongInState can be repeated for Same state
  This should not be happen..

```
ID     State     SongInState
 1      AR        Dream on
 2      AR        Dream on
```

AR can't have the same song but another state can have it.
Can i do that? I am using mySql and JAVA(just to inform).
Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a multicomun unique index on State and SongInState

Put in the table create query

```
UNIQUE KEY `UniqueStateSong` (`State` ,  `SongInState`)
```

or if it's already created

```
ALTER TABLE  `mytable` ADD UNIQUE  `UniqueStateSong` (  `State` ,  `SongInState` )
```

Comment: Woooo..great Solved. Thanks Evans.